# How do i add text to this php line of code

Tags: php

The code is

```
$product_option_value_data[] = array(
        'product_option_value_id' => $option_value['product_option_value_id'],
        'option_value_id'         => $option_value['option_value_id'],
        'name'                    => $option_value['name'] . ' (' . $option_value['quantity'] . ')',
        'image'                   => $this->model_tool_image->resize($option_value['image'], 50, 50),
        'price'                   => $price,
        'price_prefix'            => $option_value['price_prefix']
    );
```

How do i add text "Quantity Available" after `(' . $option_value['quantity'] . ')', ?`

Comment: Sorry, i've edited the post with the full code

Comment: Just extend the last string: `') Quantity Available',`....this seems to obvious though, so I'm going to guess you are actually asking something else, but haven't quite articulated it yet

Comment: I am a total noob with this. Just trying to edit my Opencart website to display stock quantity available. The current code just shows Option (Integer) So im trying to get it to show Option (Integer "Quantity Available")

Comment: Well then try what I suggested then and see if it does what you intended

Comment: It kinda works thanks. But its showing (Integer)Text. Is it possible for the text to also be in the brackets with a space after Integer EX: (Integer Text)

Comment: Yes. Just put the text to the left of the closing bracket....it's just a string, you can put whatever you want in it

Comment: It's literally just putting some extra text into a string...one of the most basic things you can do. may I suggest taking an introductory php programming tutorial, if this is a revelation to you. Start with the classic "hello world" example, and then see what happens if you change it to "hello world people".

Comment: Thanks but i'm not really into programming. More into e-commerce and usually we just hire someone to customize whatever we need but this one i was already there just needed to add that extra text so i came here for help.

Comment: This site is for programmers to help each other. It's not really a helpdesk for non-programmers to get free assistance. As it happens this is trivial enough that people didn't mind answering, because it took them 5 seconds, but don't assume you can always get help without having attempted anything yourself. The [tour] and [ask] give you more guidance on what Stackoverflow is about.

Answer (score 1):

```
$product_option_value_data[] = array(
        'product_option_value_id' => $option_value['product_option_value_id'],
        'option_value_id'         => $option_value['option_value_id'],
        // see here
        'name'                    => $option_value['name'] . 
                                    ' (' . $option_value['quantity'] . 
                                    ' Quantity Available)',
        'image'                   => $this->model_tool_image->resize($option_value['image'], 50, 50),
        'price'                   => $price,
        'price_prefix'            => $option_value['price_prefix']
    );
```